# How to secure SQL server database online

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a desktop application written in C# and using sql server 2016.
I need to host the application on computer A and the DB on computer B whereas computer B is on the internet with real IP.

The db now on real ip, which is very risky, how can I secure it, i don't want it to be exposed to the outside directly. 
For example can i use port forwarding, so i put the ip of the server in the application configuration file, and this server forward the request to the server that host the database?

Comment: You're right, it's very risky. Don't do it. Never expose a database service. You risk any number of vulnerabilities allowing your server to become a bot, fall victim of ransomware, and a whole host of other things you don't want to imagine. Expose a REST service that allows only the actions your application needs. This is probably more of a [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: At least set the correct [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/getting-started-with-database-engine-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do:

1) IP whitelist computer A on computer B.

2) Sql Server can run ssl on connection between computer A and B.

3) Sql Server can run with trusted (ca) certificate between app and sql server.

4) You could setup a webserver where you do some user/ap authentication, and only that webserver have access to computer B.

These are more or less the options you have, and you can use them all in combination.